# Правильное написание слова

Tags: правописание

Здравствуйте!
Пожалуйста, напомните, как правильно написать: "балоневые" или "болоневые" (штаны)?

Comment: Неужели в орфографическом словаре нет такого слова?

Answer (score 2):

О чем речь? Штаны из ткани болонья? 
Тогда - ***болоньевые штаны***.